# How to paint the pixel I'm currently hovering on, not the one underneath it or to the right, with the 1px pencil in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, grids, pixel, pixel-art, document-setup

I'm trying to use Photoshop for some quick pixel art. I have my 1 px grid set up, and am using the 1 px pencil to color in pixels.

However, if the crosshair is even slightly below center of the target pixel, it will instead paint the pixel below it, and the same goes for the right.

To paint a pixel accurately, I need to have the crosshair in the upper-left of the target.

This gif shows what I'm talking about:

[image: Example of problem]

Although I understand the reason for this default behavior, it is annoying for what I am trying to do.

**Is there a way to change the pixel target area, so clicking the crosshair anywhere in the grid square will paint that grid square?**

Comment: Can't replicate this. Did *you* set up the grid or is it merely the Pixel Grid Photoshop displays? If you set up the grid, I'd wager it's off a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. Turning off snap-to-grid fixes this behavior.